# Issue with an unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, listitem

So I have a list of "Top News Articles" and it only takes up a small section on the side of the page.
But if the title is longer than the width of the div, it doesnt break the sentence. It just puts the whole thing on the next line.
I havent been able to find a fix for this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrjPQo

```
<li>
    <p class="number">1</p>
    <a href="#"><h3>Virtual Reality Being Used in School</h3></a>
</li>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by adding the number inside the H3.

Or you could even use the numbering of the list, or the `::before` pseudo-element of the H3 to generate the numbering, so you don't even need the markup for it.

The example below shows the latter. Not perfectly styled, but just showing how to add numbers without having the markup for them.

```css
ul.headings {
 list-style-type: none; 
}
.headings {
  counter-reset: header-counter;
}
.headings li::before {
  /* Showing and incrementing the counter */
  content: counter(header-counter);
  counter-increment: header-counter;

  /* Some styling to make it red and round and white, etc. */
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="headings">
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

p is block element, so it takes all available width of its container. Set display:inline-block for paragraph element, or, better, substitute it with span.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and doesn't apply to this question. Both the `P` and the `H3` are already inline-blocks. Because of this, the whole `H3` wraps to the next line if they don't fit next to each other anymore. Even if the `P` would be a span, the `H3` would still jump to the next line.

Comment: @GolezTrol You're right about h3 and it will jump to next line anyway. But both P and H3 are block elements by default and both will use entire line unless other is specified. Setting display to inline-block is rather workaround than a solution and that was my point.